# How to do string interpolation in rest operation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, ecmascript-next

can someone give me the best way to remove property from an object using destructuring? I want to remove the single task from the below object

```
Object {task111: Object, task113: Object, task114: Object}

const taskId = `task${action.task.id}`;
{ [taskId]: discard, ...newState } = state;
return newState;
```

**Error:**

```
 ./src/reducers/taskReducer.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ; (32:13)

  30 |      
  31 |          const taskId = `task${action.task.id}`
> 32 |          { [taskId]: discard, ...newState } = state;
     |                    ^
  33 |          return newState
  34 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operatoren/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring), and not string interpolation, and you need to assign the property value to a variable for this to work.

```js
const state = {task111: { a: 1 }, task113: { b: 2 }, task114: { c:  3 }};

const action = {
  task: {
    id: 113
  }
};

const taskId = `task${action.task.id}`;

const { [taskId]: discard, ...newState } = state;

console.log(newState);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for nested objects, not sure though.

Comment: Your question doesn't include any nested object changes. You just remove a property, which value is an object. I've update the example to reflect the code in the question.